# Magento does not save changes to the admin panel

Tags: magento, pdo, content-management-system

After a feint, the site does not save the editing. I try to edit the text of the category, I save it, but the contents remain unchanged.
Https is configured and after transferring to the new domain everything on the site is displayed correctly

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I do not know which code to expose. Because any changes through the admin panel are not saved (edit the text of the category or add a new user)
A direct query in phpMyAdmin was able to add a new user

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the [tourguide](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask questions the right way and how stackoverflow works.